# PHP script not running on browser

Tags: php

I have installed XAMPP server on my system to be able to use PHP. But after installation, when I run any php script on the browser it does not run. I do not see any ouput. No checking the phpinfo() from local host I see that version 5.3.5 is installed
Even when running a a simple php file like where I echo a line;

I do not see anything on my browser. So, my question is do I need to make any configuration changes to my browser or system to get PHP running.

Comment: PHP scripts **never** run on the browser.

Comment: Look at the server's error log for reasons why PHP might not be running.

Comment: Where's the script located on disk, and what's the URL you're trying to load in the browser?

Comment: http://localhost/examples/Archive/test.php

The php file is located under C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examples\Archive

Comment: @Ignacio [Not 100% true...](http://www.thomas-schilz.de/MozPHP/README.html) although I'm nit-picking there, in the real world it is absolutely true.

Comment: @Hozefa, I see your posting a path to your tomcat configuration, make sure you're not confusing your Java web server with your Apache web server. I don't use XAMPP, so do excuse me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Even running a php file, to process a form does not yield required results. 

<html><body>
<?php
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$item = $_POST['item'];

//echo "You ordered ". $quantity . " " . $item . ".<br />";
echo "Thank you for ordering from Tizag Art Supplies!";

?>
</body></html>

Running the above php file on submitting the html does not work.

Comment: `The php file is located under C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examples\Archive` Unless you already setting a virtual host (and/or vhost), then the default root is on `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your scripts into /XAMPP/htdocs and then point your browser to: http://localhost/your_script.php

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is taking a look at your log files, and perhaps turning error reporting on. Put a simple script in your webroot that simply echo's a string, for example:

```
<?php echo "Hello World!";
```

with the above there is very little that can go wrong. Work from there. Take a look at your phpinfo, and see where your log files are located. Search for

```
error_log
```

for the path to your PHP error log file and maybe see if

```
display_errors
```

is on.

This is something that has a multitude of possibilities that can be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

install `phpxx-php` which is used for creating dynamic web sites

check version of php using `php -v`

if you have php55 then use:

```
yum install php55-php.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to save file as .php ; e.g. index.php and not index.html

Answer (score -1):

From [Troublespy](https://troublespy.com/viewText.php?PostId=3) here are the reasons why php might not be working in the browser:

1. You did not download a local server
2. You are using the wrong version of php
3. You put your scripts in the wrong directory
4. You have a php error and the error didn't get printed
5. Your php code is wrong or incomplete

Make sure you check all reasons.